# Redux. Как правильно использовать CombineReducers

Tags: redux

у меня есть несколько редюсеров
reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './mainReducer';
import userReducer from './userReducer';
import pageReducer from './pageReducer';
import categorieReducer from './categorieReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mainReducer, 
  userReducer,
  pageReducer,  
  categorieReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Каждый из редюсеров использует общий стейт
reducers/initialStates.js

```
const initialState = {
//.....
}
export default initialState;
```

Например, reducers/mainReducer.js

```
import initialState from './initialState.js'    
const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   // ....
}
export default mainReducer;
```

Создание store в файле redux-store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
export default store;
```

Выдаётся ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне оставить разделение на редюсеры, и при этом каждый из них будет подключаться к общему стейту

Comment: Зачем вам разделение если все равно подключаетесь к общему редюсеру ?)

Comment: чисто из эстетических соображений, как-то некрасиво выглядит, когда все редюсеры свалены в один файл

Comment: Чисто из логических соображений не делайте так.

Answer (score 0):

в вашем коде у функции createStore не верный второй аргумент
[Документация](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore)

Comment: вряд ли дело во втором аргументе, потому что без него тоже не работает

Comment: const rootReducer = combineReducers(Reducer)
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

Comment: уберите уже в других местах initialState, для чего сделан второй параметр у createStore?

Comment: второй параметр подключает redux-devtools-extension

Comment: если убрать в других местах  initialState, то как подключать другие редюсеры к общему стейту?